# how can i get array that is inside json object using org.json package in java?

Tags: java, json

i have the following json object:

```
{  
   "arguments":{  
      "a0":["x","y"],
      "a1":[1,2,3]
   },
   "fileName":"f_1_DAWBw63tWtnFpxOqd45Kxlv5RZX5Y9vGdpujcTVx.java",
   "numberOfArguments":2
}
```

And i want to get the arrays "`a0`" and "`a1`" inside `arguments` JSON object, how can i do that using org.json package?
I know how i get `numberOfArguments` and `fileName`like this:

```
String fileName = json.get("fileName");
int numberOfArguments = json.getInt("numberOfArguments");
```

but i don't know how for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into : [the javadoc](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)
i'll do

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("arguments").getJSONArray("a0");
```

Then you could iterate on the array either with

```
jsonArray.iterator()
```

or

```
jsonArray.toList()
```